# Uploading/playing mp3 files using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first "real" Rails project - "modernizing" an old website for a church choir and am building it in Rails.  They currently have a practice page with a list of links to mp3 files stored on their server.  I would like to store the mp3 files in a database and have created a model for the songs - title:string, part:string (tenor, soprano, etc), audio:binary (this is the mp3 file).  When I submit the form, the audio field is nil - the other fields save correctly.  Should I be using a Gem for uploading/saving the mp3 files?  I've come across CarrierWave, but have only seen it used with images.  I was under the impression that the binary field in active record was for preserving the original file format.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you have decided to store the mp3's in the database rather than using a file system?

Comment: No reason other than just being a noob.  :)  I'll also look into using a file system (which I assume will be specific to whatever site I end up choosing to host).  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There are pros and cons with using db or filesystem, but personally I would let the database do what it does well and manage data and let the filesystem do what it does well and manage files. Would be easier to manage mp3's if you do use a filesystem and in that case I would recommend Paperclip - also make sure your form is using multipart to upload files and if it's using remote (AJAX), consider using the remotipart gem too.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Paperclip worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use file upload instead of saving it into database then you can use `paperclip` . please have a look at it https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - ewkruljac specifically states that he wants to store the mp3 files in a database as binary. Paperclip doesn't do that.